# http requests from certain users have query string that breaks cache

Tags: php, apache, http, proxy

I have a simple php intranet web application. Now certain users have difficulties in following a trivial link. They say it opens a blank web page and no content is displayed.

For most users and me it works perfectly fine and hence I have trouble finding the actual issue. But I'm pretty sure it's a network issue not directly related to my application.

In the Apache log files I can see that all affected users have a numeric query string appended to all request also to css and js files. Example:

```
js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?_=1373882009110
```

This breaks the browser cache and as far as I can tell also the application (I'm uncertain why it would break it). i suspect they have a different proxy and that proxy is doing this stuff automatically? Can that be the issue? This leaves the question what else the proxy might be doing that break my application?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs

Comment: Above link is from apache access log. there is nothing in error log.

Comment: In that case, we do not have enough information to be able to do anything other than take random guesses at whats up. Start by ensuring you are logging errors and Find out what the user last clicked, see if that shows up in your access log or if something is stopping it before it even gets to your server.

Comment: Thats the issue yes. My question is if someone actually knows why this happens and what the solution is. And yes the access log show what the user clicked. But as said everything works fine for me and also other users.

Comment: You have not given any more information so we still do not know the answer. Please re-read my last comment and YOU do those tasks to try and find out what the problem is. No one here can do those things for you, and no one here can tell you what the problem is without more information from YOU.

Comment: sure someone who had the same issue can answer my question. It's obvious you don't know the answer... Read my comment: The issue is there is no more information. Get it now?

Comment: Of course there never will be any more information until you try to get some. No one else can answer your question as they are not running your system with your unknown code on your unknown platform with users clicking the same unknown link through the same unknown proxy and getting the same unknown issue happening. But don't let all those unknowns stop you believing that there is some psychic here that can magically know the solution without a clue what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues where caused by server alias only valid on some sites and using absolute path. Changing it to the full server name and using relative path solved the issue. Eg. from `http://myalias/mypage` to `http://myserver.com/mypage`.